# Class "let" stuck in infinite loop

Tags: vba, excel

Forgive any stupid errors in the code, because this is my first attempt at using classes and I couldn't find any tutorials online that put it in really, *really* plain terms for fools like me.  I did my best to sort of follow the MS guide at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716315(v=vs.60).aspx, but I don't really understand what I'm doing anyway, which makes it hard to interpret what I should be changing.

I am trying to make a class that stores three pieces of data, two integers and a string.  I put this in a class module called `tdata`:

```
Sub tdata()

Dim tnumber As Integer, tacct As Integer
Dim ttype As String

Public Property Get t_acct() As Integer         'don't forget the account number!
    t_acct = tacct
End Property

Public Property Let t_acct(ByVal newval As Integer)
    t_acct = newval
End Property

Public Property Get t_numb() As Integer         'T1, T2, or T3 as applicable
    t_numb = tnumb
End Property

Public Property Let t_numb(ByVal newval As Integer)
    t_numb = newval
End Property

Public Property Get t_type() As String          'PF or MW
    t_type = ttype
End Property

Public Property Let t_type(ByVal newstr As String)
    t_type = newstr
End Property

End Sub
```

I then called it in my function using

```
Set t_info = New tdata
t_info.t_acct = wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(d, 1)             'd is just a row counter in a for loop
t_info.t_numb = Right(wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(d, 4), 1)
t_info.t_type = wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(d, 6)
references(CStr(wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(d, 5))).Add t_info
```

(this is not all the code, of course, but just the part where it is called)

I've got `Option Explicit` and all that fun stuff on and everything compiles fine, but when it gets to the second line of the function snippet, where it tries make `t_info.t_acct` equal to something, it heads to the `Let` function for that one, and stays there...forever.  Specifically, it bounces between

```
Public Property Let t_acct(ByVal newval As Integer)
    t_acct = newval
```

forever.  Why is this?  How do I make it set (err, let) t_acct equal the thing I want it to?

Comment: remove the underscore, you are looping back in.  The let is your way into the 2nd and 3rd line of your code variable declarations

Comment: Which underscores?  I removed the underscore in the t_acct, t_numb, and t_type under the let procedures, and it ran through successfully, but it didn't set it equal to anything - it was still 0 (0 was not in the cell in question).  I tried removing other underscores, but they returned errors (mostly "can't assign to read only property, except of course that removing both of the underscores yielded the original problem)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your issue is here:

> ```
> Public Property Let t_acct(ByVal newval As Integer)
>     t_acct = newval
> End Property
> ```

That should be assigning the encapsulated field (`tacct`), not itself.

---

I'm going to give you my secret recipe: whenever I create a new class module, I start with a private type:

```
Option Explicit
Private Type TData 'assuming class module is named 'Data'
    Number As Integer
    Account As Integer
    AccountType As String
End Type
```

And then, I declare a private field of that type, named `this`:

```
Private this As TData
```

Some might argue that `this` makes everything oh so confusing because `this` (the private field) isn't `Me` (the object instance) and in other languages `this` refers to the object instance and whatnot - if it confuses you, give it whatever name you like then (`backing` and `encapsulated` are perfectly fine too!).

Now all the properties become crystal-clear, and consistent:

```
Public Property Get Number() As Integer
    Number = this.Number
End Property

Public Property Let Number(ByVal value As Integer)
    this.Number = value
End Property

Public Property Get Account() As Integer
    Account = this.Account
End Property

Public Property Let Account(ByVal value As Integer)
    this.Account = value
End Property

Public Property Get AccountType() As String
    AccountType = this.AccountType
End Property

Public Property Let AccountType(ByVal value As String)
    this.AccountType = value
End Property
```

`Property Get` members return `this.ThePropertyName`, and `Property Let` members *assign* `this.ThePropertyName` with the supplied `value` - always. If a property needs to be an object type that isn't get-only, you'll want to supply a `Property Set` member:

```
Private Type TData
    '...
    SomeObject As Object
End Type
Private this As TData    

Public Property Get SomeObject() As Object
    Set SomeObject = this.SomeObject
End Property

Public Property Set SomeObject(ByVal value As Object)
    Set this.SomeObject = value
End Property
```

---

Avoid disemvoweling, prefixes and unreadable/meaningless names, use `PascalCase` for public members, favor consistency, and whatever you do, avoid underscores in public class members' names - otherwise the day you want to start using `Implements` is the day your code stops compiling. Follow that, and your class modules should always be crystal-clear.

Comment: ahaa, this private type idiom is pretty interesting. Although I don't see immediately its additional benefits, but I can imagine. It already permits to have the exact same name for the private fields and the property getters/letters. And the `this` name, so challenging choice for C++/Java programmers! Nice. Will adopt.

Comment: Only thing probably questionable about `this`.. might conflict if one wants to rewrite some classes in C#. I guess you already heard that, as you mentioned :)

Comment: @A.S.H the immediate benefit is the consistency in naming, which makes *wrong* code, *look wrong*; another perhaps less obvious benefit, is that serialization becomes a no-brainer - you just `Put#fn,,this` and you're done! In C# I use `private readonly int _someInt;` and `public int SomeInt { get { return _someInt; } }` - I only ever use `this` in C# when I *need* to refer to the class instance.. which is pretty much never (same as VBA's `Me`, come to think about it).

Comment: Truly interesting. You should think of sharing a comprehensive discussion of its benefits through some dedicated thread when you have time. It's more than a simple answer to a question. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @A.S.H - I'm a convert on using a type for private members (except for the `this` part).  `this.Number` *looks like* a recursion to my C# eyes - my name of choice is "`backing`".

Comment: @Comintern agree, and almost already decided to adopt it with a different name. My immediate thought on `this` was for eventual porting to C#. Precisely, imagining one wants to write some *automatic porting tool*, I see some difficulties that could have been easily avoided.

Comment: @A.S.H if the automatic porting tool is worth its salt then it'd pick up that the identifier is a keyword, and would call it `@this` with a *verbatim* specifier ;-)

Comment: Yup, it's a possible solution, among others. But personally I'd just avoid it and make it no-brainer, too sissy maybe :P. Although I have to admit, the name `this` is really *elegant* in this context!

Comment: I could compromise for `encapsulated` and call it a win =)