# Excel-vba: Create a class with a dictionary as a member variable

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have a `Scripting.Dictionary` as a member variable of a class.

I tried the following as suggested by [Putting dictionaries into classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262391/putting-dictionaries-into-classes/43263253)

But I get the impression that Mathieu's answer doesn't work for excel vba.

I put the following in a class module.

```
Option Explicit
Private dict As Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub
```

I get the error "User defined type not defined" for dict.

What went wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime, from the VBE, Tools | References, then scroll down and check the option for Microsoft Scripting Runtime:

[image]

And then you could even reduce your code as:

```
Option Explicit
Private dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

End Sub
```

Otherwise you must use late-binding.

```
Option Explicit
Private dict As Object ' Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub
```

Note that neither of these options will work on Mac OS.